# Advantages to using "type" keyword in python type aliases

Tags: python, python-3.x

Prior to python 3.12, my understanding was that the line `mta = int` created a type alias named `mta`, but with 3.12, this line could (should?) be written as `type mta = int`, even if the prior syntax is still supported.  These aren't interchangeable, though.  For example, `isinstance` will accept the first as a legal second argument, but will fail with the second.  (It seems that in the second case, `isinstance(3, mta.__value__)` works, but this seems awkward.)

I read [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#type-aliases) to mean that the syntaxes are both supported to allow for backward compatibility, not that they are functionally different.  Given this behavior, when is it advantageous to use the `type` keyword?  Are there cases in which the simple (pre-3.12) assignment are inferior?

For example:

```py
>>> mta = int
>>> isinstance(3, mta)
True
>>> type mta = int
>>> isinstance(3, mta)
...
TypeError: isinstance arg 2 must be a type, a tuple of types, or a union
```

Comment: See [PEP 695 #Generic Type Alias](https://peps.python.org/pep-0695/#generic-type-alias). The most advantageous aspect is aligned with the rest of PEP 695, whose primary purpose is to be able to declare/define generic types without separate declaration of type variables.

Comment: This is pretty well covered in the PEP, but the three key advantages are 1) type statements support type parameter syntax, 2) the value of the type alias is lazily evaluated, and 3) type aliases can be better differentiated from ordinary variables

Comment: Got it, thanks.  I think my confusion was around the fact that a _type alias_ (using the keyword) cannot be used as a _type_, whereas the pre-3.12 assignments are (exactly) types.  Thanks.